# enum class in java

Tags: java, enumeration

Hi i got a code to understand so here's the  enum code :

```
   package com.unice.miage.igift.enumeration;

  /**
   *
   * @author Root
   */
  public enum BookEnum {
      BOOK("BOOK"),
      MAGAZINE("MAGAZINE");

        private String bookText;

         BookEnum(String bookText){
        this.bookText = bookText;
          }

          public String getBookText() {
    return bookText;
           }

     public void setBookText(String bookText) {
       this.bookText = bookText;
       }

    }
```

i can't find the objective of this enum

Thank you in advance

Comment: What do you mean "*i can't find the objective of this enum*"?

Comment: Enums are basically used when there is a well-defined, fixed set of values which are known at compile-time. You can use [EnumSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) as well, if you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "objective" of the enum probably isn't in the *declaration* of the enum, it is probably in the **usage** of the enum.

From the limited info that is here, it is probably used to avoid "stringly-typed" code which would have used the string "BOOK" and "MAGAZINE" all over the place.

For example:

```
// old code
void doSomething( String bookType )
{
    if (bookType.equals("BOOK")
    {
        // do something with book
    }
    else if (bookType.equals("MAGAZINE")
    {
        // do something with magazine
    }
    // OOPS, this code is broken if someone adds a new type of book, or uses the string "Book" or "book"
}

// new code
void doSomething( BookEnum bookType )
{
    switch (bookType)
    {
         // cases for each enum value
    }
}
```

the new version of the method does not allow you to pass in non-existant book types, or arbitrarily cased strings that may or may not have worked in the "old code"

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any benefit of the extra `bookText` field.

Following simple enum will do the same,

```
public enum BookEnum {
    BOOK,
    MAGAZINE;
}
```

You can get the string like this,

```
BookEnum book = BookEnum.MAGAZINE;
String bookText = book.name();
```

Comment: Don't you find it a disastrous fail to have a setter on an enum? I mean OP's code.

Comment: +1 The bookText field would have been helpful if they had used custom names and not the enum's actual name.